# How to Group by 2 different columns and Make it to behave differently in certain situations in Sql with SSRS

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have 2 foreign key columns in one table named as Subs (Say like PONo, InvoiceNo). In a single record, either PO or Invoice or Both will have some data (Without Null). When, Both PO and Invoice have data, I need to consider only InvoiceNo not PONo.

I have to use the above query to generate reports. So, I need to group by either PONo or InvoiceNo to send to the specific Supplier. I dont have any idea how to group by two columns into one. Especially, when both PoNo and InvoiceNo are same in two records, I need to generate 2 different letters instead of 1. Please consider the below case,

```
  SubsId                  PONO         Issue           InvoiceNo          Supp

    1                     001          XX              null              abc
    2                     null         YY              001               abc
    3                     null         ZZ              001               abc
```

If the above table values are the case, then I need to get the result something like this,

**Letter 1**

```
    PONO        Issue         InvoiceNo       Supp

    001          XX           null            abc
```

**Letter 2**

```
    PONO        Issue         InvoiceNo       Supp

    null         YY           001             abc
    null         ZZ           001             abc
```

Because, I need to show the report with either PONo or InvoiceNo as single group.

I searched everywhere to group by 2 columns into 1 group in SSRS. But, I didn't find any solution. So, Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a Calculated Field to your Dataset like this:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!InvoiceNo.Value)
  , "P" & Fields!PONO.Value
  , "I" & Fields!InvoiceNo.Value)
```

Call it `GroupNumber` or whatever you like. It looks like `PONO` and `InvoiceNo` are both strings in your example so I've just concatenated a type identifier string to them. If they are numeric you could cast them as strings in the above expression as required.

This accomplishes your two goals, i.e. being able to use both `PONO` and `InvoiceNo` together as a single grouping item, but also being able to differentiate between the two types so `PONO` and `InvoiceNo` values with the same number *don't* get grouped together as one group item.

Then, when setting up tablix groups in the report, you group on this new field. It never needs to be displayed anywhere, it's just used for the grouping; this should work as you require.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [TSQL Coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) statement, a TSQL Case When Statement, or an SSRS IIF(compareison, Truepart, falsepart)

**TSQL Coalesce**

```
select colalesce(InvoiceNo, PONO) as Number, Issue, Supp
from mytable1 join mytable2 etc
Group By colalesce(InvoiceNo, PONO), Issue, Supp
```

**TSQL Case when**

```
Select case When InvoiceNo is null then PONO
           else InvoiceNo END as Number, Issue, Supp
    from mytable1 join mytable2 etc
    Group By case When InvoiceNo is null then PONO
           else InvoiceNo END , Issue, Supp
```

**SSRS**

Number TextBox expression

```
=IIF(Fields!InvoiceNo.value ="", Fields!PONO.value, Fields!InvoiceNo.value)
```

Comment: The above suggestion is okay. But I need to group by two columns into one in SSRS. If i Include the new column (Number) to group by in SSRS, then If same PONo and InvoiceNo present in 2 records then it ll appear in same letter as 2 records but should appear in 2 different letter.

Comment: In that case @Ian Prestons suggestion of a Calculated Field would be a better fit for what you want then.